# Compare values in temp-tables; update table accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider two temp-tables:

```
select object_a into #a from dba.object_a group by object_a

object_a
--------
123
456
789

select object_b into #b from dba.object_b group by object_b

object_b
--------
123
999
```

I would like to update table `#b` with a column that marks objects that exist in `#a` as well in `#b`:

```
alter table #b add InTableA int;

update #a set InTableA = (
  case when object_a in (select object_a from #a) then 1 else 0 end
)
```

This however doesn't work: I keep getting the error `invalid column name InTableA`??

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are updating the wrong table:

```
update #b
--------^
    set InTableA = (case when object_b in (select object_a from #a) then 1 else 0 end)
------------------------------^
```